# Wordcloud and list of list

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, word-cloud

I am trying to create wordclouds with the following data:

```
my list= [[],
     [],
     [],
     [],
     [],
     [],
     [],
     [],
     [],
     [],
     [],
     [],
     [],
     [],
     [],
     [],
     [],
     [],
     [],
     ['EMF'],
     ['body'],
     [],
     [],
     [],
     [],
     ['water', 'juice'],
     ['What', 'are', 'u', 'doing'],
     [],
     [],
     [],
     [],
     [],
     [],
     [],
     ['EVENT'],
     ['christmas'],
     [],
     ['shalala'],
     ['happy'],
     []]
```

Generally I do

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS, ImageColorGenerator

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

corpus = " ".join(x for x in my_list)
df_wordcloud = WordCloud(background_color='white',max_font_size = 50).generate(corpus)

plt.imshow(df_wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

but this time I got the error:

> TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found

Do you know how to create a wordcloud from a list of lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing `" ".join(x for x in my_list)` is effectively equivalent to `" ".join(my_list)`, which is trying to join all the sub-lists together, causing the error you see.

Instead, you want to "flatten" those internal lists first turning them into strings:

```py
corpus = " ".join(" ".join(x) for x in my_list)
```

Or even:

```py
corpus = " ".join(map(" ".join, my_list))
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us try `explode`

```
s = pd.Series(l).explode().dropna()
Out[195]: 
19          EMF
20         body
25        water
25        juice
26         What
26          are
26            u
26        doing
34        EVENT
35    christmas
37      shalala
38        happy
dtype: object
```